# Xamarin Android Google Map v2 SetOnCameraChangeListener Method

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am working on android map app in xamarin android. I want to handle the zoom event of map. Can anybody tell me how can I do this in xamarin android using map.SetOnCameraChangeListener ..

Regards

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit late of an answer, but this really helped me. Should have everything you need.

http://pastebin.com/dgdiDk2N

Basically you need to implement the interface:

```
public class MapTab : Fragment, GoogleMap.IOnCameraChangeListener
```

Then you can set the listener as such:

```
map.SetOnCameraChangeListener (this);
```

And you will also need to add the method OnCameraChange:

```
public async void OnCameraChange (CameraPosition cameraPos)
{
    //Do your things here when the camera updates
}
```